# PayPal Java ButtonManager SDK service calls fail on SSLenabled server due to SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, ssl, paypal, https

I have installed SSL/TLS on a webserver that hosts a webapp which uses the PayPal [Java ButtonManager SDK](https://github.com/paypal/buttonmanager-sdk-java).  When using that API on this server, all SOAP service calls to PayPal's servers (such as to https://api.paypal.com/2.0) fail with the seemingly most ambiguous exception I have dealt with.  A java.net.SocketException is thrown with the message "Connection reset" which I think at least tells me that the issue is on my end.  However, this is not news to me because when I run the same webapp locally or on a different web server without SSL/TLS, it works perfectly fine.

I have TLS v1.2 installed with SHA-256 (RSA) encryption which I think meets PayPal's requirements.

Here is the Exception stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:704) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:675) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1536) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
        at com.paypal.core.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:77) ~[paypal-core-1.4.4.jar:?]
        ... 102 more
```

What could possibly be causing this?  Any help that would help me narrow this down would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked for a firewall blocking the connections? Have you tried other tools (like curl, openssl s_client, telnet..) to reach the API from this specific server? Can you do a packet capture to see where exactly the RST occurs, i.e. beginning of connection, inside TLS handshake, after handshake...